# Unable to Load Assets in Flutter Project

Tags: flutter

I'm pretty new to Flutter and so far I have found everything so easy and pleasant to work through but now I'm stuck on something that seems really straightforward - I can't seem to use local assets.

I got stuck on a tutorial for the audioplayers package when I couldn't load a local asset mp3 file, even with the tutorial's code. I would get: FlutterError unable to load asset: (assets/audio.mp3).  I went over my pubspec.yaml and everything was correct and correctly indented. The file was definitely located right where it was supposed to be, in my assets folder. I got frustrated and figured I would do a simpler test.
I tried running code from an image widget tutorial, pointing to a .png file in my assets folder.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 u /override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Image from assets"),
        ),
        body: Image.asset('Capture.PNG'), //   <-- image
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

While it does not crash, it just doesn't display the photo. I see the AppBar and a gray screen. The file is in the correct location (project_file > project_file > assets)

The file is named correctly (Capture.PNG)

The pubspec.yaml specifies the photo:

```
flutter:
 assets:
    - assets/Capture.PNG
```

I have tried cold rebooting the emulator, I have run flutter clean and flutter pub get before emulating, I have restarted my computer, I have added another directory (/images) and then removed it. I have tried using a .jpg instead of a .png file and nothing has worked. I keep hoping to find a human error somewhere but I've been over everything so many times it seems unlikely. I can't seem to load a simple photo, much less figure out mp3 playback.

Comment: The `pubspec.yaml` indentation looks malformed - does it still work with the `assets` key being indented only one space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace it with:

```
Image.asset('assets/Capture.PNG')
```